# Which open source hosting facilities accept LPPL?

Tags: best-practices, comparison, contribute

Is there a list of open source hosting facilities which accept (La)TeX packages published under the LPPL license? Which open source hosting facility did you chose for your (La)TeX project and why?

Comment: This feels like the sort of question that should be community wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The LPPL is relatively unusual, and so for sites which limit to open source licenses you may have to ask. In the past, I've used [BerliOS](http://www.berlios.de/): they seemed quite flexible about the license provided you provide a reason.

On the other hand, there are sites which host in a license-neutral way. For example, both [GitHub](http://github.com/) and [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org/) allow you to use any license. (These sites tend to make their money from closed-source material from paying customers.)

Thus the question tends not to be 'which host supports the license', but is more to do with other features.

Comment: BerliOS has a bad security history and is run by Mr. Schily, so I suggest to  stay away from it if you can. But hat's just my personal opinion.

Comment: I second BitBucket, I host my LaTeX package (under LPPL of course) there now.

Comment: @Martin Schröder: My issue with BerliOS was more that it's rather old-fashioned, hence using BiBucket for my own code nowadays (although with my UK-TUG hat on we're using GitHub).

Comment: @Joseph: Note, that a space ends the user name, so you just wrote to `@Martin` which was me, because I was the last Martin which commented here. Write `@MartinSchröder`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Interesting - I'd have coded it to look back and spot that there are two names, then try the next word to 'break the deadlock'.

Comment: BTW: Berlios will be closed on 31.12.2011, see http://developer.berlios.de/forum/forum.php?forum_id=37450

Answer (score 5):

We're using Launchpad for the TeX-SX "Answers to Packages" package (start with [What are your favourite TikZ/PGF answers?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1220/86) and follow the links).  I remember that I had to select something like "Other free licence" when I signed up and there was a notice saying that they would assess the licence and get back to me if it wasn't okay.  They haven't gotten back to me so I *assume* that they're okay with the LPPL.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue with Open Source hosters having problems with the LPPL is a thing of the past since the [OSI](http://opensource.org/licenses/LPPL-1.3c) and the [FSF](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html) now accept the LPPL. For example [sourceforge.net](http://www.sf.net) simply [wants an OSI approved license](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sitelegal/wiki/Terms_of_Use#a3.USERCONTENT).

Answer (score 3):

To date, [Sourceforge](http://www.sf.net/) has no LPPL in the license category listing. Since now LPPL is an [OSI-approved license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/lppl), I opened a ticket about adding LPPL to the listing. Nevertheless, I consider Sourceforge a friendly place to host opensource projects. And there's also [GitHub](http://github.com/). `=)`

Answer (score 3):

Consider simply dual-licensing your package. It’s pretty common to have Open Source projects use multiple licenses and just let the user pick what suits them best.

This way, you can license your package as LPPL, but at the same time have any other license that satisfies your code hoster. For instance, the README file of my `minted` package contains the following passage:

> This work may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions of the LaTeX
>   Project Public License, either version 1.3 of this license or (at your option)
>   any later version.
>   Additionally, the project may be distributed under the terms of the new BSD
>   license.

This is both legal and safe.

Comment: @Downvoter: please leave comment explaining your downvote.

Comment: One benefit of the LPPL (over GPL or BSD) is that the user is only allowed to do a fork if he changes the package name. Wouldn't dual-licensing nullify this benefit?

Comment: @Axel True. Is that a problem in practice? Wouldn’t a modified package of the same name by a different author simply be rejected by CTAN?

Comment: Don't know, will they? Should I try to upload a modified version of minted to CTAN? ;-) Anyway, I think this can get a problem in practice. An example: There was a modified version of KOMA-Script bundled with a LaTeX document template, published on a website. Markus Kohm was able to abandon that because of the license.